# How to make gitlab runner access EC2 instance to make deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I create a script to make deploy but every time throw this error:
"Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Host key verification failed."

My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
make_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add bash
    - apk add git
    - apk add openssh
    - bash scripts/deploy.sh
    - echo "Deploy succeeded!"
  only:
    - master
```

deploy.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=gitlab+deploy-token-44444
pass=passwordpass
gitlab="https://"$user":"$pass"@gitlab.com/repo/project.git"

ssh-keygen -R 50-200-50-15

chmod 600 key.pem

ssh -tt -i key.pem ubuntu@ec2-50-200-50-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com << 'ENDSSH'

rm -rf project
git clone $gitlab
cd project
npm i 
pm2 restart .

ENDSSH

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your authentication type instead of using username & password, use ssh key exchange.

This way, your script will not be prompted with username & password input.

But before you do that, you should first create ssh keys and upload the public key to your repository settings, it will serve as your primary authentication between the instance and the gitlab server.

[More info here.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/)

Test your connection.

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

Comment: This part of gitlab works, I tested in locally, the error is the connection with ec2, I can't enter in the terminal of there

Comment: You should done those steps in EC2 itself, and after you verify the host key create an image of the configure ec2 instance as an AMI so that in case you need to redeploy another instance you don't need to reconfigure it again.